# Which side of a gym track should I walk on to be courteous to runners?

Tags: gym

My gym has a track that is used for walking and running. I often walk on it at a time when there are also runners. Unfortunately, I don't know if I should be walking on the inside or the outside of the track.

Other guests at the gym do both, which ultimately becomes worse since then runners have to either go through the middle or slow down. While I can't control others, I would rather know the more courteous place to walk so that I don't contribute to the problem.

If it matters, this is a second story track overlooking exercise equipment below. I sometimes see people carrying weights on the track, and have wondered if they might be better off walking on the outside so that if they were to drop the weights, there is no chance it would go over the railing and hurt someone below.

Comment: Talk to your gym, see if they can put up advice signs for people to stick to one or the other if walking / running.

Comment: Why not take walks outside?

Comment: @vidstige In my area, it gets well below -20 degrees Celsius in the winter and rather icy. Indoor tracks at the gym are much better in that weather.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slower traffic should be to the outside of the track. Everywhere I've been (high school tracks, college/university tracks, and community tracks) this has been the convention.